# Extract only date from date time column pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have data frame as shown below

```
Date_Time             
2019-02-27 10:00:00
2019-08-07 20:23:00
2019-02-24 00:00:00
```

from the above I would like to extract date only in new column as shown below.

Expected Output:

```
Date_Time               Date
2019-02-27 10:00:00     2019-02-27
2019-08-07 20:23:00     2019-08-07
2019-02-24 00:00:00     2019-02-24
```

Tried below code

```
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.floor('D')
```

But not providing required output

Comment: try `df['Date'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.normalize`

Comment: @Datanovice dt.date will extract just the date

Comment: @Meow yes but it will return an object, normalize keeps it as a datetime dtype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have *Date_Time* column as a string, start from converting it
to *datetime* type:

```
df.Date_Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_Time)
```

Then run:

```
df['Date'] = df.Date_Time.dt.date
```

Other solution can be almost like yours, but with the format
fitting the actual formatting of the source data (year-month-day):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.floor('D')
```

or even without format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.floor('D')
```

Caution: Although both variants give the same printout, the
actual results are different, what you can check running e.g. `df.iloc[0,2]`.

- In the first case the result is *datetime.date(2019, 2, 27)* (just date).
- But in the second case the result is *Timestamp('2019-02-27 00:00:00')*
  (timestamp with "zeroed" time part).